# How to merge MySQL rows in to another array's key and values in PHP?

Tags: php

Below I am fetching three records from a database.

```
$Select_Query = "select level,sum(score) score,sum(total_time) total_time from user_score WHERE DATE(created_date) = DATE(NOW()) and user_id='2' group by level";
$result_query = mysql_query($Select_Query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result_query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_query)) {
    $level=$row['level'];
    $score=$row['score'];
}
```

I want the levels and score to be assigned to a new array as keys and values like below.

```
//$data = array (
    '1' => 25,
    '2' => 28,
    '3' => 27,
    '4' => 35,
    '5' => 40,
    '6' => 20,
    '7' => 50,
    '8' => 43,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/array_combine).

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $array2 = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
    print_r(array_combine($array1, $array2));
?>
```

Output: http://codepad.org/ZmGdcvqq

Comment: I don't think it required to use array_combine() function here.

Comment: When it can be done while looping itself than why should we add one more extra line here... Does't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_query)) {
    $data[$row['level']] = $row['score'];
}
print_r($data);
```

**Output:**

```
array(
  '1' => 25,
  '2' => 28,
  '3' => 27,
  '4' => 35,
  '5' => 40,
  '6' => 20,
  '7' => 50,
  '8' => 43,

);
```

Comment: I am using a graph that shows dynamic content from db.But when i am using it in my php
    page, where i have html form,only the graph is showing but html form is not showing.I  am 
    using  header("Content-type: image/png") to show the graph on the page.
    What should i write so that the graph as well as my html form will be shown?

Comment: @user1755949: this is not what you explain in question and something new. My answer is as per your question.